# Spacemacs, python, refactoring - Change name of variable

Tags: spacemacs, python, refactoring

I know that there are ways in emacs to refactor python scripts and e.g. change the name of a variable. What is the best way to do this in spacemacs? The standard refactoring only seems to offer a few things around the imports.

rope is installed on my system.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know rope is the only option for now since redbaron is at quite an early stage and hasn't been adopted by emacs yet. But there is an awesome rope wrapper called "Traad" made by Austin Bingham, who still maintains it. Here's its homepage: https://github.com/abingham/traad. He also gave a talk in EuroPython 2014 about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvV5OrVk24c.

Definitely worth a try.